# How to get the selected item _id in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am new to meteor and js and trying to build some app using meteor.
I want to get the _id for further use. Before I just use this._id to get the object id but this time I cannot.

Here is the html:

```
{{#each player in getPlayers}}
  <div class="card test">
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">{{player.name}}</a>
    </div>              
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Here is the js:

```
Template.playerList.helpers({
  'getPlayers'(){
    var player = PlayerLists.find().fetch();
    return player;
  }
});
```

and the function I try to catch the _id:

```
'click .test': function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var currentId = this._id;
  currentPlayer = PlayerLists.findOne({_id:currentId});
  console.log(currentId);
}
```

PlayerLists is a collection and play is document. I try to just the selected player's _id but currentId shows undefined whenever I click the player.

Could anyone help me with it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple solution:

```
{{#each player in getPlayers}}
    <div class="card test">
     <div class="content">
      <a class="header useThisEvent" data-id="{{_id}}>{{player.name}}</a>
     </div>              
    </div>
{{/each}}

'click .useThisEvent': function() {
event.preventDefault();
//there you have id of selected item. Its imporatant to use event.currentTarget
var id = $(event.currentTarget).data('id')
}

//Try to simple you code:
Template.playerList.helpers({
'getPlayers'(){
return PlayerLists.find().fetch();
}
});

{{#each player in getPlayers}} i suggest to change for {{#each getPlayers}}
```

btw in 'this' probably you have window object, not _id from PlayerList collection. Try to use Template.instance() or Template.currentData() but this methods sometimes can return something else.